# Registration with Azure AD B2C custom policy fails due to missing claim information

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am currently investigating the possibilities to send emails from a custom policy in Azure AD B2C through a custom email service provider. To do so, I was following this tutorial from the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid.

Since we have been using custom policies for quite some time now, I tried to adopt the tutorial right away to our own custom policy: we use a multistep registration process with the email verification step being the first and the personal data step being the second step.

My efforts have been successful with connecting the email service provider, sending the code through it and proceed to the second step of the registration process after successfully verifing the email address.

However, when I want to complete the second step of the registration and have the user be actually created in AD I see the following error in the frontend:

> Unable to validate the information provided.

To gain further insights I activated developer mode in the policy and checked the traces in Application Insights where I found the following error:

> The claim type "signInNames.emailAddress", designated as the identifier claim type, could not be found in the claims collection for the claims principal in tenant id "B2C_1A_signup_notificationtest".

caused in the technical profile `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail`. However, as you can see below in that technical profile the aforementioned claim type `signInNames.emailAddress` is derived throught the partnerClaimType directive in the input claims of the technical profile:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
    <InputClaims>
<!-- THIS IS THE LINE I AM REFERRING TO: -->
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress"
                    Required="true"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <PersistedClaims>
        <!-- Required claims -->
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress"/>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password"/>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="unknown"/>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies"
                        DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration"/>

        <!-- Optional claims. -->
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Salutation"/>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName"/>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname"/>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country"/>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Company"/>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Kundennummer"/>
    </PersistedClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource"
                     DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress"/>
    </OutputClaims>
    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common"/>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

So my question would be: where can I look to debug further? Am I looking in the right place or does the error message mean something completely different?

Also as a side note: due to the nature of the identity experience frameworks configuration, there is a lot of xml involved. Therefore I have posted the relying party policy file that also includes the relevant parts for the service connection as a gist here: https://gist.github.com/mmaedler/0a555fc3f9e6036e235a15419e7afdd5

*UPDATE* Additionally I have added all relevant (hopefully) Technical Profiles as well as the UserJourney itself to this new gist: https://gist.github.com/mmaedler/19ab309897f3a7d993816eb34adc7edb

Also I have used your advise to investigate further. Since I overwrite the Technical Profile `LocalAccountSignUpMultiStep-1` to replace the current built in code verification with the one using our mailing backend it suggests the output of this is lacking the email address in a field/format that is expected by the following technical profile in step 2. I have added a new OutputClaim to `LocalAccountSignUpMultiStep-2` with a `ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"` which lead to a new input appearing on registration step 2. Entering an email address there ended in a successful signup and token creation.

Comment: Not enough info in the git. We need the user journey and every technical profile referenced before AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail Is run to give an exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

Misunderstanding, this XML snippet input claim translates to - "Please find me this user by searching for the `email` through all users' `signInNames.emailAddress` attribute".

The error from the log states that, when this lookup operation was performed, the value for `signInNames.emailAddress` was **null**. This means that the claim `email` was never output as an output claim in any previous technical profile called by an orchestration step.

Look back through all technical profiles called prior to this and determine which claim has the user email inside it. Make sure that claim is output by a technical profile that is called by an orchestration step.

Comment: As per my update in the original post, that did not yield a solution. Any further hints? Also could you elaborate on the meaning of the `PartnerClaimType` attribute? I couldn't find something about it in the documentation...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and I resolved it by removing `PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email"` from the technical profile that contained the DisplayControl as its DisplayClaim.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Jas Suri's comment, I was able to solve my problem.

I simply added a `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />` in the previous OrchestrationStep and also added the transformation

```
<!-- Copy SignInName to Email Claim Type -->
<OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopyMailAddress" />
</OutputClaimsTransformations>
```

which looks like this:

```
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="CopyMailAddress" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

inserted. Thus the `signInName` (which I use in all OrchestrationSteps) was copied to the ClaimType `email` and so the `email` claimType was no longer empty.